# std::async thread pool continue execution without blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a Thread Pool where each thread must be a waiting thread and keep listening to new tasks to process them asynchronously (the processing takes some long time). However, in the following code I am not able to get this behaviour. The problem is that when I create the thread pool, they execute successfully the first task given. The *process()* function reaches de `return 0;` while threads are computing tasks, but it never returns to *main()*. It stands in the `v.wait(l, [&] {return !tasks.empty(); });` line, that is, it still waits for new tasks to be pushed into the tasks queue and that never happens. I've readed that it's something related to the std::future destructor: If I am not wrong, I think that when *process()* reaches the return, the std::future destructor is called and it waits till all the threads ends, but they never ends!

Here's the code:

```
static int callings = 0;

class ThreadPool
{

private:
    std::queue<int> tasks;
    std::mutex m;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> finished;
    std::condition_variable v;

public:

    void push_task(int arg) {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        tasks.push(arg);
        v.notify_one(); // wake a thread to work on the task
    }

    void read_tasks() {

        while (true) {

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            if (tasks.empty()) {
                //waits till new task
                v.wait(l, [&] {return !tasks.empty(); }); //after completing the first task, the program stays here forever
            }

            int task = tasks.front(); // read task
            tasks.pop(); //delete task

            //run the task
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5 * 1000)); //simulate computation

        }//while true
    }

    void create_thread_pool(int m_threads_count) {

        for (int t_i = 0; t_i < m_threads_count; t_i++) {

            finished.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,[this] { read_tasks(); }));
            printf("Thread %d is doing work...\n", t_i);
        }
    }
}; //ThreadPool


int process(){

    ThreadPool pool;

    if(callings == 0)
    {
        pool.create_thread_pool(4);
    }

    //give some task to do...
    pool.push_task(callings);

    callings++;

    return 0; //point reached but never returning to main
}

int main(){

    while(true){

        // do things...

        process();

        // do more things...
        // this does not execute, how to solve this?

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**How can I return to main() while the threads keep waiting for new tasks without blocking?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::async` creates a thread with a return value that needs to be synced at some point. What you need is more primitive - just try using `std::thread`. That spawns a thread with no synchronization implied.

Comment: Do you realize you destroy your `ThreadPool` after stepping out of `process`? You should move it to `main` and pass reference/pointer to `process`